# Что делает колёсико "мышки" или Скроллинг по-русски

Tags: переводы

С помощью колёсика компьютерной мышки можно двигать вверх/вниз изображение (текст) на экране компьютерного монитора.

По-английски это называется **mouse wheel scrolling**. Кое-кто так и пишет кириллицей: **скроллинг**.

**Вопрос: как этот процесс назвать, используя славянские корни?** Или хотя бы более традиционные слова. Прокрутка? Промотка?

А если в привязке к этому колёсику? Прокрутка колёсиком мышки? Или колесом мыши? **Как это СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЕ написать литературным русским языком?** Если вообще возможно. Трудно с этой новой компьютерной терминологией иногда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, прокрутка – так говорят. И чаще, чем скроллинг. Вот промотка – так не говорят.

Конкретная фраза нужна, может, скроллинг и больше подойдёт.

Comment: >Конкретная фраза нужна, может, скроллинг и больше подойдёт.

Ну фраза, извините если не по теме форума, английская: **mouse wheel scrolling**. Настройка такая в программе, возле которой галочку ставят. Возможность проматывать колесом мыши. Надо написать по-русски, ясно, понятно, ГРАМОТНО, и по возможности максимально коротко.

Comment: Я бы написал: "Использовать колесико мыши [для прокрутки]". "Для прокрутки" – если хватает места.

Comment: Вроде бы неплохо. Спасибо. 

Посмотрим, может быть ещё будут варианты.

Answer (score 1):

В словарях: колесо прокрутки мыши.

Comment: Спасибо.

>Вопрос: как этот процесс назвать

Comment: Скорее всего " прокрутка".

Answer (score 0):

Просмотр (обзор, скольжение) колёсиком мыши.

Для просмотра (обзора, скольжения) вращайте (используйте) колёсико мыши.

Бегунок просмотра (обзора, скольжения).

Просмотр (обзор, скольжение) бегунком.

Comment: Добавил вам плюс за ответ и откатил его к первоначальному варианту. Будьте добры в следующий раз не выражаться.